# If Custom Field is Specific Value then do Something...(Radio Buttons)

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, radio-button, conditional-statements

I am stuck on figuring out how to display different data based on what input is made in a custom field.

I have radio buttons as my input field in a registration form, with 3 options. X, Y, Z.

They are saved in a custom field called member_status, this is saved as user_meta

My code effort is something liek this...but I can't figure it out!

```
global $current_user;

get_currentuserinfo();

$userID = $current_user->ID;

$memberstatus = get_user_meta($userID,'member_status',true);

If $memberstatus = X {

// do something here if X

} elseif $memberstatus = Y {

// do something here if Y

} elseif  $memberstatus = Z {

// do something here if Z
```

and the question is:.......

I do not know how to construct the IF statements correctly, this is just a guess above....

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: so my code does not work.....I don't know how to write the IF statements to check if the status is X, Y or Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really save it as meta with `member_status` then:

```
if($memberstatus == 'X'){
    // do something here if X
} elseif ($memberstatus == 'Y'){
    // do something here if Y
} elseif ($memberstatus == 'Z'){
    // do something here if Z
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` instead of `=` for comparisons.

`==` is the comparison operator and `=` is the assignment operator.

Also don't forget to wrap your boolean conditions in brackets `(` and `)`

```
if($memberstatus == X){

}
elseif($memberstatus == Y){

}
// and so on
```